# Consumiendo un JSON desde android ¿Que falla?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, webservice

Estoy intentando obtener un Json de un recurso web y convertirlo a string para mostrarlo por pantalla. Estoy usando android Studio para ello y no consigo consumir ese recurso. Alguna idea de que está mal
PS: En el manifests tengo añadidos los permisos de INTERNET y de ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

```
public void getData(String URL) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(URL);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()){
        text.concat(reader.nextString());
    }
}
```

Comment: que error recibes?

Comment: Si no especificas el error, el cual encuentras en el LogCat pueden ser varias causas.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes hacer peticiones a internet desde el hilo principal, puedes hacerlo desde un asyntask:
El siguiente enlace te será de utilidad: http://www.proyectosimio.com/es/programacion-android-asynctask-conectar-a-internet-y-leer-documentos-json/

PD: acostumbra a poner el error que te muestra logcat.

Comment: Ese era el problema, ya está solucionado. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El método debería devolver el recurso "String" o lo que quieras y no ser "void" si quieres utilizar el resultado.

```
    // read the JSON results into a string
    String jsonResult = in.readLine();
    return jsonResult;
```

Además conviene que hagas esta actividad en un hilo o thread secundario.